# Python NamedTemporaryFile appears empty even after data is written

Tags: python, python-3.x, temporary-files

In Python 2 it was easy to create a temporary file and access it. However with in Python 3 it seems that is no longer the case. I'm confused on how I can get to the file I create with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() so I can call a command on it.

For example:

```
temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
temp.write(someData)
subprocess.call(['cat', temp.name]) # Doesn't print anything out as if file was empty (would work in python 2)
subprocess.call(['cat', "%s%s" % (tempfile.gettempdir(), temp.name])) # Doesn't print anything out as if file was empty
temp.close()
```

Comment: Works for me? `temp.name` gives me the correct file name (`"/var/folders/ck/s38sycld0tvgb5qhmqtf750r0000gn/T/tmp7ejqww3s"`)

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "doesn't work"? That is not an adequate problem specification. And, as it stands, it works just fine for me...

Comment: Okay, I have a guess: Call `temp.flush()` after the write call. The data you're writing is buffered.

Comment: Thanks L3viathan! This seems to have fixed my problem

Comment: This isn't specific to NamedTemporaryFile -- you can get the exact same behavior with `temp = file.open('filename', 'w')` too.

Comment: Thanks @L3viathan , saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 32):

The problem is with flushing. The file output is buffered for efficiency reasons, so you must `flush` it for the changes to be actually written to the file. Additionally, you should wrap this into a `with` context manager instead of explicit `.close()`

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
    temp.write(someData)
    temp.flush()
    subprocess.call(['cat', temp.name])
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is seeking. The pointer related to the file points to the end of the file (so the next write would continue after what has been written previously, but that also means the read returns empty string). Seeking to position `0` fixes it.

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w+b') as target_f:
    target_f.write(b"abcde")
    target_f.seek(0)
    assert target_f.read() == b"abcde"
```

worked for me, the flushing did nothing.

Comment: Works like magic! Thank you for this wonderful solution. :D