# Python subprocess.call() invoking gnuplot then evince on a newly created file sometimes has no output

Tags: python, subprocess, gnuplot

I've been trying to use Python 3.4 to call a simple gnuplot script and then display the result (a .ps file) using evince. My code looks like this:

```
plotfile = "plot.p"

with open(plotfile, "w") as plt:
    lines = ['set term postscript',
             'set output "speed.ps"',
             'set xlabel "Time"',
             'set ylabel "Speed"',
             "plot '{}' u 2:4 title 'speed' with lines".format(infile)
            ]
    lines = map(lambda x: x + '\n', lines)
    plt.writelines(lines)

    # Call gnuplot and evince
    subprocess.call(['gnuplot', plotfile])
    subprocess.call(['evince', 'speed.ps'])
```

However, `evince` often doesn't display the file. I can create the file correctly using

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['gnuplot', plotfile])
```

but if I try to immediately open the file, by calling

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['gnuplot', plotfile])  
subprocess.Popen(['evince', plot.ps])
```

the file often doesn't display correctly, I'm assuming because the first command doesn't finish in time.  To fix this issue, I've tried

```
process = subprocess.call(['gnuplot', plotfile])
```

or

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['gnuplot', plotfile])
process.wait()
```

but it both cases no .ps file is even created.  The only thing that works (and not always) is

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['gnuplot', plotfile])  
time.sleep(1)
subprocess.Popen(['evince', plot.ps])
```

but that is really ugly.

So my questions are:

1) Why might waiting for the process to finish (using either `subprocess.call()` or `wait()`) prevent the .ps file from even being created?
2) Is there some solution that doesn't involve using "sleep"?

Versions:

- CentOS 6.6
- Python 3.4
- Gnuplot 4.6
- Evince 2.28.2

Comment: can't you pass the script in gnuplot command line instead?

Comment: "no .ps file is even created" -- the place to start is figuring out *why* you get a failure in that case (since the code given here *should* work in that scenario), instead of just trying going on to try other things. Unfortunately, we won't be able to help you with that unless you provide a [mcve] (which implies, for example, code that actually retrieves or creates a plotfile).

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised at all if your plotfile was, say, referred to by a still-open file handle that hadn't been explicitly flushed, or something along those lines, but that kind of thing is pure speculation until and unless you actually provide us with complete and self-contained code (validated to cause the problem when run in isolation) we can use to see the problem ourselves and validate proposed fixes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I think the the file handle explanation is exactly right actually.  I was doing all of this with the "plotfile" open.   I didn't realize that would cause a problem with subprocess.  Can you explain why that happens?  Thank you!

Comment: I've added more of my code to demonstrate what the problem was.

Comment: Try to add `reset` at the end of your gnuplot script.

Comment: ...so, this is an effective duplicate of [NamedTemporaryFile appears empty even after data is written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46004774/python-namedtemporaryfile-appears-empty-even-after-data-is-written)

Comment: BTW, editing an answer into a question is frowned on here. Editing one question into a different question *after it's answered*, likewise. Since the comments that lead you to an answer were comments, rather than answers, it's a little bit of a corner case -- but if you don't object, I'll be editing this back to be asking the original question (but with enough details to actually be answerable); you're welcome to add your own solution as an answer yourself, as well (vs. editing it into the question, which makes it immune from the usual voting/commenting/etc. process).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes please edit the question however you like.   That would be instructive for me.

Comment: Great, thank you @CharlesDuffy!   This is all clear to me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you've had some misleading test results leading you down the wrong path. Using `subprocess.call()` or calling `.wait()` on a `Popen` object **does** genuinely wait for the program that was invoked to exit. What's *not* guaranteed, however, is whether the result of your `plt.writelines()` calls will be flushed to disk or will still be in an in-memory buffer by the time `gnuplot` is started.

Given the following code:

```
plotfile = "plot.p"

with open(plotfile, "w") as plt:
    lines = ['set term postscript',
             'set output "speed.ps"',
             'set xlabel "Time"',
             'set ylabel "Speed"',
             "plot '{}' u 2:4 title 'speed' with lines".format(infile)
            ]
    lines = map(lambda x: x + '\n', lines)
    plt.writelines(lines)

    plt.flush() ### <-- EITHER CALL THIS OR MOVE THE BELOW OUTSIDE THE with BLOCK

    # Call gnuplot and evince
    subprocess.call(['gnuplot', plotfile])
    subprocess.call(['evince', 'speed.ps'])
```

...absent the `flush()`, the `plt` file isn't guaranteed to have all contents flushed before `subprocess.call()` is invoked; lines can still be buffered and not available to other programs yet.

Closing a file flushes it, so moving the `call()`s outside the `with` block will also solve your problem.