# system vs call vs popen in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, system-calls

```
cmd = 'touch -d '+date_in+' '+images_dir+'/'+photo_name
os.system(cmd)
```

Doesn't work

```
subprocess.call(['touch','-d','{}'.format(date_in),'{}'.format(images_dir+'/'+photo_name)])
```

Doesn't work

```
subprocess.Popen(['touch','-d','{}'.format(date_in),'{}'.format(images_dir+'/'+photo_name)])
```

Works!

Why? What am I missing in first two cases?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python --version
Python 2.7.13
```

Actual code snippet:

```
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    if(response.getcode() == 200):
        photo_file = response.read()
        with open(images_dir+'/'+photo_name,'wb') as output:
            output.write(photo_file)
            #cmd = 'touch -d '+date_in+' '+images_dir+'/'+photo_name
            #subprocess.Popen(['touch','-d','{}'.format(date_in),'{}'.format(images_dir+'/'+photo_name)])
            subprocess.check_call(['touch','-d','{}'.format(date_in),'{}'.format(images_dir+'/'+photo_name)])
        with open(images_dir+'/captions/'+photo_name+'.txt','wb') as output:
            output.write(photo_title)
    else:
        print 'Download error'
except Exception as message:
    print 'URL open exception {}'.format(message)
```

Comment: What exactly does "Doesn't work" mean?  If there was an error message, you need to post it.

Comment: No error message. It quietly went on to next line of code

Comment: also replace `call` by `check_call` and report the results. I have a hard time believing this, no offense

Comment: `'{}'.format(images_dir+'/'+photo_name)` yuck! => `os.path.join(images_dir,photo_name)`

Comment: `check_call` completed quietly just like `call` with no effect on file date.

Comment: can you give a real example of a touch command with full parameters?

Comment: Added actual code.

Comment: This is very much a FAQ. See ie. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46004774/python-namedtemporaryfile-appears-empty-even-after-data-is-written for a prior instance of this question, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567676/python-subprocess-call-invoking-gnuplot-then-evince-on-a-newly-created-file-so for another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it's clear:

```
with open(images_dir+'/'+photo_name,'wb') as output:
    output.write(photo_file)
    #cmd = 'touch -d '+date_in+' '+images_dir+'/'+photo_name
    #subprocess.Popen(['touch','-d','{}'.format(date_in),'{}'.format(images_dir+'/'+photo_name)])
    subprocess.check_call(['touch','-d','{}'.format(date_in),'{}'.format(images_dir+'/'+photo_name)])
```

My assumption is: you're still in the `with` block, so if `check_call` or `system` is performed, it ends, then the file is closed, setting the date again and ruining `touch` efforts.

With `Popen`, the process is performed *in the background*, so when it's executed, the file is already closed (well, actually it's a *race condition*, it's not guaranteed)

I suggest:

```
with open(images_dir+'/'+photo_name,'wb') as output:
    output.write(photo_file)
subprocess.check_call(['touch','-d','{}'.format(date_in),'{}'.format(images_dir+'/'+photo_name)])
```

so the file is properly closed when you call `check_call`

Better written:

```
fullpath = os.path.join(images_dir,photo_name)
with open(fullpath ,'wb') as output:
    output.write(photo_file)
# we're outside the with block, note the de-indentation
subprocess.check_call(['touch','-d','{}'.format(date_in),fullpath])
```

Comment: Ah.. `with` block. Thanks that fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `touch` at all for this; use `os.utime` instead.

```
import os

try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
except Exception as message:
    print 'URL open exception {}'.format(message)
else:
    if response.getcode() == 200:
        photo_file = response.read()
        f = os.path.join(images_dir, photo_name)
        with open(f,'wb') as output:
            output.write(photo_file)
        os.utime(f, (date_in, date_in))

        f = os.path.join(images_dir, 'captions', photo_name + '.txt')    
        with open(f, 'wb') as output:
            output.write(photo_title)
    else:
        print 'Download error'
```

Note that the date/time arguments to `os.utime` must be integer UNIX timestamps; you'll need to convert your `date_in` value from whatever it currently is first.

Comment: 1.Why? 2.Won't `os.utime` inside `with` block cause the original issue in this code?

Comment: 1. It's better to avoid forking new processes if possible. 2. Probably; there's no compelling reason for it to be inside anyway.