# Change Date Modified for file after writing in Python

Tags: python, file, date

I am having a strange issue with python when I try to change the "Date Modified" field value in Windows. Specifically, if I write to the file and then try to change its Date Modified attribute, the change fails (the Date Modified becomes the time I ran the python script). However, if I don't write to the file (if I comment out the out.write function call) the Date Modified time is correctly set to 11/2017.

The Date Accessed time is set as expected in both situations.

Below is my code (python 2.7):

```
import os
import time
import datetime

out = open("out.test", "wb")
#comment out the write line to get this to work
out.write("hi")
out.flush()
out.close

fileLocation = "out.test"
year = 2017
month = 11
day = 5
hour = 19
minute = 50
second = 0

date = datetime.datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day, hour=hour, minute=minute, second=second)
modTime = time.mktime(date.timetuple())

os.utime(fileLocation, (modTime, modTime))
```

Interestingly, if I use a separate python process (i.e. run python  in another cmd prompt) to alter the Date Modified, that also works as well.

Is there some other flush-like function I need to call in order to properly set the Date Modified time if I write to the file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in this faulty line:

```
out.close
```

this *doesn't* close the file (it does nothing useful, just reading the reference of the function, and not calling it). Normally not a big deal because python closes files on exit, but not here.

When the process terminates/the file handle is garbage collected, an implicit `close` is called on the file, which sets the modification date to current time.

So `utime` changes the time when file is open, but the file is closed afterwards, and the modification time is reset: it seems to have no effect.

(a similar issue has been asked & answered here: [system vs call vs popen in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48709793/system-vs-call-vs-popen-in-python))

The fix is of course:

```
out.close()
```

Note that there's a subtle difference when writing or not to the file. If you don't write to the file, the implicit `close` call probably doesn't have to update the file time, which explains that it works.

Final advice: use context managers to avoid issues like that. You won't have to call `close` so often:

```
with open("out.test", "w") as out:
    out.write("hi")
    out.flush()

# file is closed when exiting "with" block
```